# How to implement RLS but still be able to compare it with the total value

Tags: powerbi, dax

Within my company there are five divisions. I want to create a dashboard to map the average sales numbers. Each division has to compare his sales numbers with the average sales numbers of the entire company. But the divisions can not see the numbers from the other divisions. So I have to use RLS. How can I ignore this RLS with a measure so that I am able to see the total average sales numbers.  It has to be a measure, calculated column will not work in the end for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using ALL(), you should be able to achieve this. ALL() will eliminate any filters getting applied on that table.

Comment: @balaji it does not remove RLS, RLS is always applied first, and it can not be removed.

Comment: Add another table with totals that everyone has access to.